# Recover incomplete(?) video files

Tags: windows-7, audio, video

I have two mp4 video files(shot with a Nokia Lumia Phone) that cannot be played. While recording, the memory card got completely filled and it went in accessible from the phone. So I removed the card from it and connected to my PC and copied the file to PC. But opening the file in KM player shows the following warning:

```
audiodg.exe
KMPlayer.exe
--------------------
PLAYBACK INFO
--------------------
[Video Info]
Decoder -No codec
[Audio Info]
Decoder -No codec
[Basic Video DSP]
Internal brightness: 100%
[Advanced Video DSP]
+PictureProperty(S/W Process)
  -LumGain: 128
  -LumOffset: 0
  -Gamma: 100
  -HUE: 0
  -Saturation: 64
+Video Plugin
[Audio DSP]
+Pre amplification: Main: (100%)
+Auto Volume Control
+3D Effect: 5000
+Audio Plugin
[Subtitle Settings]
+Draw Mode(Selected): Overlay
+Draw Mode(In use): On Overlay
+Text Rendering Method: Window(GDI)
[KMPlayer]
+Version: 3.9.1.135(11,786,048, 3/27/2015 9:38:30 AM)
+libcodec.dll: (4,548,096, 1/18/2013 1:17:48 PM)
+libmplay.dll: (538,112, 10/31/2012 2:29:32 PM)
+PProcDLL.dll: 1.0.0.1(1,769,472, 2/25/2008 11:37:04 AM)
+LibDTS.dll: (178,174, 12/5/2008 1:12:20 PM)
+liba52.dll: (73,063, 12/5/2008 1:11:10 PM)
+libfaad2.dll: (335,155, 12/5/2008 1:07:06 PM)
+libmad.dll: (123,036, 12/5/2008 1:12:30 PM)
+libmpeg2.dll: (154,644, 12/5/2008 1:12:42 PM)
+theora.dll: (200,864, 12/5/2008 1:13:32 PM)
+OggVorbis.dll: (1,165,312, 2/25/2008 11:37:00 AM)
+xviddll.dll: (758,319, 12/5/2008 1:28:36 PM)
+Old_QUARTZ.DLL: 6.01.05.0319(770,048, 2/25/2008 11:37:00 AM)
+AboutDll.dll: (105,472, 10/3/2005 10:42:18 AM)
+DTView.dll: (98,304, 2/21/2012 2:57:36 PM)
+ImLoader.dll: (856,064, 2/25/2008 11:35:22 AM)
+MediaInfo.dll: 0.7.72.0(3,910,480, 1/7/2015 8:23:00 PM)
```

Opening it with VLC does not play anything but the **traffic cone**.When opened in Media Player Classic, it says **Cannot render this file**(haven't tried GOM Player yet). When I tried to convert it with Format Factory, it says the format is not recognized, media infor by Format factory showed the following:

```
General
Complete name                    : [path]\WP_20150708_12_54_17_Pro.mp4  
Format                           : MPEG-4  
Format profile                   : Base Media / Version 2  
Codec ID                         : mp42  
File size                        : 179 MiB
```

How can I recover this video file?

**UPDATE:**
I tried the solution given [here](https://superuser.com/a/539083/400355), but got the following output:
[image]

Comment: Try opening it in VirtualDub - http://www.virtualdub.org/download.html

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler I can't open the file, **The file [path] is of an unknown or unsupported file type**.

Comment: Hmm, how about if you install one of the K-Lite multimedia codec packs? http://www.codecguide.com/download_kl.htm then try again?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler I have them already and I think its a full package.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler I do not want my question to be closed, it was just a jock.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Wait, you told me to install K-Lite codec pack, what should I do after that?

Comment: Retry opening the file in VirtualDub or similar. But if you already have them, it doesn't matter. I have had good luck with VirtualDub reading partial files before, but if you have codecs to read the files normally, and virtualdub is no help, then I don't know what else.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler That's all right, my bad luck. Anyway, thanks for your help. I expect an answer like [this](http://superuser.com/a/809053/400355)

Comment: Don't know if its suitable material, but if you make the file available to download I can have a play with it under Linux for you.  I wonder if the problem is moov atom, or if ffmpeg or similar can be coerced into helping ?

Comment: @davidgo can I check those in my own, as I have some linux distros with me(Ubuntu, Kali Lunux and Linux Mint)?

Comment: @davidgo ... in Live USB.

Comment: This question makes no sense.  It sounds like the video isn't complete, and because it isn't complete, it is also considered to be corrupted.  I assume your only trying to repair what is there?

Comment: @davidgo Question updated.

Comment: @Ramhound@DacidPostill Why Duplicate?

Comment: @RogUE - 3 other people voted.  I don't have to explain further then the generated explanation.

Comment: @Ramhound But the answer simply doesn't work.

Comment: @RogUE - My actually point is trying to understand the reason you called me out when 4 other people voted.

Comment: @Ramhound It is because I can't notify more than 2 users per comment and I see you around here often. So I called you out.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I have a few pieces of advice.

First, try to use a program like **Do-It-Yourself Video Repair Software (VRT)**  (alternatively called **HD Video Repair Utility** ) which is intended for this sort of problem. You can learn more about and download this particular software at the following link:

http://grauonline.de/cms2/?page_id=5

Or, I'm reasonably sure there are other programs out there that do essentially the same thing, but which might be cheaper or freeware.

If someone can suggest such software, I think that'd be useful to include in the comments.

Failing all else...

Upload your video file to the Internet, I'd suggest Google-Drive or www.wikisend.com , and then give us the URL to the file in the comments. One of us can try to fix it on your behalf, and then we share with you the finished-product, and share with the rest of the users the process by which we were able to get the video working and recovered.